# Winsock2 can't connect to ip

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

First of all i already disabled my firewall, added rules for the port (TCP&UDP), port forwarded on my router.

I'm trying to do a login system with winsock but client wont connect to the server whenever I'm inputting a ipv4. But if i use 127.0.0.1 it doesn't seem to occur.
Tried with my second pc with diffrent network doesn't work as well.

client:

```
    string ipAddress = myip;            
int port = myport;                      

cout << "========================" << endl;
cout << "client started..." << endl;

WSAData data;
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
if (wsResult != 0)
{
    cout << "init failed error: " << wsResult << endl;
    return 1;
}

SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cout << "cant create socket error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

sockaddr_in hint;
hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
hint.sin_port = htons(port);
inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "cant connect to server error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

char buf[4096];
string userInput = "testingfromclient";

int sendResult = send(sock, userInput.c_str(), userInput.size() + 1, 0);
if (sendResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
    int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
    if (bytesReceived > 0)
    {
        cout << "from server : " << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;
    }
}

closesocket(sock);
WSACleanup();
```

server:

```
cout << "started" << endl;
while (true) {
    cout << "============= connection starting =============" << endl;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (wsOk != 0) {
        cerr << "can't init" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "cant create socket" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    int bindResult = bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    cout << "============= connection started =============" << endl;

    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];      
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];   

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST); 
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " <<
            ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }

    closesocket(listening);

    char buf[4096];
    string senddata;

    while (true) {
        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

        int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (bytesReceived > 0) {
            cout << "============= recieved bytes from client =============" << endl;
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", bytesReceived);
            if (buf == "testingfromclient") {
                senddata += "friend";
            }
            else {
                senddata += "stranger";
            }

            send(clientSocket, senddata.c_str(), bytesReceived, 0);
            std::cout << "senddata: " << senddata << std::endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
        else if (bytesReceived == 0) {
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

    }

    closesocket(clientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    std::cout << "============= connection ended =============" << endl;
}
std::cout << "ended" << endl;

return 0;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Use a tool like wireshark on both ends to monitor your packets and make sure they flow as required. Also add error checks. Why do you trust inet_pton to be successful?

Comment: im downloading wireshark right now. So I should check for bind, listen and inet_ntop?

Comment: Check *everything*. If  function can fail, check it, every time.

Comment: If the client is on the WAN side of a router, and the server is on the LAN side, make sure your router is configured for port forwarding properly, and that the client is connecting to the router's public WAN IP, not to the server's private LAN IP.

Comment: Proabably both of them are in lan side and im not trying to do with LAN IP's. For example i want to do them like string ip = "71,123,543,12"; something like that

Comment: @n.m. I'm now checking everything but i can't seem to get the packets from Wireshark. By the way conenct error : 10060